# how to reorder cutree result for confusion matrix?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I´m doing HCA with infrared spectrocopic data from 300 samples, so that my dataframe is 300x3606. the variables are in range: new_hca_data <- new_hca_data_all[,6:3606]

```
hc.new <- hclust(dist(new_hca_data_region_sc, method = "euclidean"), method = 'ward.D')
clusterCut <- cutree(hc.new, k =5) 
dput(clusterCut)
c(a1 = 1L, a2 = 1L, a3 = 1L, a4 = 1L, a5 = 1L, a6 = 1L, a7 = 1L, 
a8 = 1L, a9 = 1L, a10 = 1L, a11 = 1L, a12 = 1L, a13 = 1L, a14 = 1L, 
a15 = 1L, a16 = 1L, a17 = 1L, a18 = 1L, a19 = 1L, a20 = 1L, a21 = 1L, 
a22 = 1L, a23 = 1L, a24 = 1L, a25 = 1L, a26 = 1L, a27 = 1L, a28 = 1L, 
a29 = 1L, a30 = 1L, a31 = 1L, a32 = 1L, a33 = 1L, a34 = 1L, a35 = 1L, 
a36 = 1L, a37 = 1L, a38 = 1L, a39 = 1L, a40 = 1L, a41 = 1L, a42 = 1L, 
a43 = 1L, a44 = 1L, a45 = 1L, a46 = 1L, a47 = 1L, a48 = 1L, a49 = 1L, 
a50 = 1L, a51 = 1L, a52 = 1L, a53 = 1L, a54 = 1L, a55 = 1L, a56 = 1L, 
a57 = 1L, a58 = 1L, a59 = 1L, a60 = 1L, a61 = 1L, a62 = 1L, a63 = 1L, 
a64 = 1L, b1 = 1L, b2 = 2L, b3 = 2L, b4 = 2L, b5 = 2L, b6 = 2L, 
b7 = 2L, b8 = 2L, b9 = 2L, b10 = 2L, b11 = 2L, b12 = 2L, b13 = 2L, 
b14 = 1L, b15 = 2L, b16 = 2L, b17 = 2L, b18 = 2L, b19 = 2L, b20 = 2L, 
b21 = 2L, b22 = 2L, b23 = 2L, b24 = 2L, b25 = 2L, b26 = 2L, b27 = 2L, 
b28 = 2L, b29 = 2L, b30 = 2L, b31 = 2L, b32 = 2L, b33 = 2L, b34 = 2L, 
b35 = 2L, b36 = 2L, b37 = 2L, b38 = 2L, b39 = 2L, b40 = 1L, b41 = 2L, 
b42 = 2L, b43 = 2L, b44 = 2L, b45 = 2L, b46 = 2L, b47 = 2L, b48 = 2L, 
b49 = 2L, b50 = 2L, b51 = 2L, b52 = 2L, c1 = 3L, c2 = 4L, c3 = 1L, 
c4 = 3L, c5 = 3L, c6 = 3L, c7 = 3L, c8 = 3L, c9 = 3L, c10 = 3L, 
c11 = 3L, c12 = 3L, c13 = 3L, c14 = 3L, c15 = 3L, c16 = 3L, c17 = 4L, 
c18 = 1L, c19 = 3L, c20 = 3L, c21 = 3L, c22 = 3L, c23 = 3L, c24 = 3L, 
c25 = 3L, c26 = 3L, c27 = 3L, c28 = 3L, c29 = 3L, c30 = 3L, c31 = 3L, 
c32 = 4L, c33 = 1L, c34 = 3L, c35 = 3L, c36 = 3L, c37 = 3L, c38 = 3L, 
c39 = 3L, c40 = 3L, c41 = 3L, c42 = 3L, c43 = 3L, c44 = 3L, c45 = 3L, 
c46 = 3L, c47 = 4L, c48 = 1L, c49 = 3L, c50 = 3L, c51 = 3L, c52 = 3L, 
c53 = 3L, c54 = 3L, c55 = 3L, c56 = 3L, c57 = 3L, c58 = 3L, c59 = 3L, 
c60 = 3L, k1 = 5L, k2 = 5L, k3 = 5L, k4 = 5L, k5 = 5L, k6 = 5L, 
k7 = 5L, k8 = 5L, k9 = 5L, k10 = 5L, k11 = 5L, k12 = 5L, k13 = 5L, 
k14 = 1L, k15 = 5L, k16 = 5L, k17 = 5L, k18 = 5L, k19 = 5L, k20 = 5L, 
k21 = 5L, k22 = 5L, k23 = 5L, k24 = 5L, k25 = 5L, k26 = 5L, k27 = 5L, 
k28 = 5L, k29 = 5L, k30 = 1L, k31 = 5L, k32 = 5L, k33 = 5L, k34 = 5L, 
k35 = 5L, k36 = 5L, k37 = 5L, k38 = 5L, k39 = 5L, k40 = 5L, k41 = 5L, 
k42 = 5L, k43 = 5L, k44 = 5L, k45 = 5L, k46 = 1L, k47 = 5L, k48 = 5L, 
k49 = 5L, k50 = 5L, k51 = 5L, k52 = 5L, k53 = 5L, k54 = 5L, k55 = 5L, 
k56 = 5L, k57 = 5L, k58 = 5L, k59 = 5L, k60 = 5L, k61 = 5L, k62 = 1L, 
k63 = 5L, k64 = 5L, f1 = 4L, f2 = 4L, f3 = 4L, f4 = 4L, f5 = 4L, 
f6 = 4L, f7 = 4L, f8 = 4L, f9 = 4L, f10 = 4L, f11 = 4L, f12 = 4L, 
f13 = 4L, f14 = 4L, f15 = 4L, f16 = 4L, f17 = 4L, f18 = 4L, f19 = 4L, 
f20 = 4L, f21 = 4L, f22 = 4L, f23 = 4L, f24 = 4L, f25 = 4L, f26 = 4L, 
f27 = 4L, f28 = 4L, f29 = 4L, f30 = 4L, f31 = 4L, f32 = 4L, f33 = 4L, 
f34 = 4L, f35 = 4L, f36 = 4L, f37 = 4L, f38 = 4L, f39 = 4L, f40 = 4L, 
f41 = 4L, f42 = 4L, f43 = 4L, f44 = 4L, f45 = 4L, f46 = 4L, f47 = 4L, 
f48 = 4L, f49 = 4L, f50 = 4L, f51 = 4L, f52 = 4L, f53 = 4L, f54 = 4L, 
f55 = 4L, f56 = 4L, f57 = 4L, f58 = 4L, f59 = 4L, f60 = 4L)
```

I do have  columns in which I know 5 classes my data belong to, and I want to make a confusion matrix (CM) to check the accuracy.
I'm doing like this:

```
nome_clusters <- c("ANF", "BZD", "CAN", "FEN", "CAT")
tabela_ordenada <- table(clusterCut, new_hca_data_all$grupo)
tabela_ordenada  # CAT & FEN columns are in wrong order
clusterCut ANF BZD CAN CAT FEN
         1  64   3   4   4   0
         2   0  49   0   0   0
         3   0   0  52   0   0
         4   0   0   4   0  60
         5   0   0   0  60   0
ordem_colunas <- nome_clusters
tabela_ordenada <- tabela_ordenada[, ordem_colunas]
print(tabela_ordenada)
      
clusterCut ANF BZD CAN FEN CAT
         1  64   3   4   0   4
         2   0  49   0   0   0
         3   0   0  52   0   0
         4   0   0   4  60   0
         5   0   0   0   0  60
```

Now I can perform CM analysis.

```
hca_gr
[1] "anf" "bzd" "can" "cat" "fen"
matriz_confusao <- as.table(matriz_confusao)
colnames(matriz_confusao) <- hca_gr
rownames(matriz_confusao) <- hca_gr
# Calcule as métricas de avaliação
avaliacao <- confusionMatrix(matriz_confusao)
# Show results
print(avaliacao)
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

    anf bzd can cat fen
anf  64   3   4   0   4
bzd   0  49   0   0   0
can   0   0  52   0   0
cat   0   0   4  60   0
fen   0   0   0   0  60

Overall Statistics
                                          
               Accuracy : 0.95            
                 95% CI : (0.9189, 0.9717)
    No Information Rate : 0.2133          
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : < 2.2e-16       
                                          
                  Kappa : 0.9374          
                                          
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : NA              

Statistics by Class:

                     Class: anf Class: bzd Class: can Class: cat Class: fen
Sensitivity              1.0000     0.9423     0.8667     1.0000     0.9375
Specificity              0.9534     1.0000     1.0000     0.9833     1.0000
Pos Pred Value           0.8533     1.0000     1.0000     0.9375     1.0000
Neg Pred Value           1.0000     0.9880     0.9677     1.0000     0.9833
Prevalence               0.2133     0.1733     0.2000     0.2000     0.2133
Detection Rate           0.2133     0.1633     0.1733     0.2000     0.2000
Detection Prevalence     0.2500     0.1633     0.1733     0.2133     0.2000
Balanced Accuracy        0.9767     0.9712     0.9333     0.9917     0.9688
```

problem is: clusterCut results ordenate clusters in a way I'm having to figure out what is the order of the columns, and then reorder them to make a confusion matrix afterwards, otherwise, the result is wrong.
In this case it was kind easy to figure, but I have other results no so easy.
clusterCut vector contains names, the convention is: ai(i=1-60) = anf, b = bzd, c = can, f = fen, k=cat. new_hca_data_all$sigla is the column in my df that's the source for this.

my question is: how can I make a code that fix this order, using the info I have, without guessing it like I did?